# Create array from string - PHP

Tags: php

I have a string from which I need to get an associative array. I can freely modify the string to look like an array, but I still can't get an array out of it.
I tried explode, json, etc.

```
 $string = $row->id . ',' . $row->title . ',';
// 1,Home,3,Services,6,Service 1,7,Service 2,2,Products
```

example

```
    public function Menu($parent = null) {
$query = $this->menuManager->getPublicMenus()->where('parent', null)->order('sort_order');
        if ($this->menuManager->getPublicMenus()->count() > 0) {
            $menu = '';
            foreach ($query as $row) {
                $menu .= $row->id . ',' . $row->title . ',';
                $menu .= $this->Menu($row->id);
            }
            return $menu;
        }
    }
```

I need output:

```
array
1 => "Home"
3 => "Services"
6 => "Service 1"
7 => "Service 2"
2 => "Products"
```

Comment: Can you just store the string as JSON, saves a lot of problems.

Comment: `$array[$row->id] = $row->title;`

Comment: I added the code. How to serialize to json? `json_encode($string)` I tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you HAVE TO use the string.

```
$input = '1,Home,3,Services,6,Service 1,7,Service 2,2,Products';

$keysAndValues = explode(',', $input);

$result = [];
$count = count($keysAndValues);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i+=2) {
    $key = $keysAndValues[$i];
    $value = $keysAndValues[$i+1];
    
    $result[$key] = $value;
}
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/SRiVv).

### output

```
array(5) {
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Home"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "Services"
    [6]=>
    string(9) "Service 1"
    [7]=>
    string(9) "Service 2"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "Products"
}
```

---

I see you added an example. To get the array, its much cleaner to do this in your Menu method:

```
$menu = [];
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $menu[$row->id] = [
        'title' => $row->title,
        'children' => $this->Menu($row->id)
    ];
}
return $menu;
```